# Error en el delimitador al importar .txt

Tags: r, importación

EL problema es el siguiente. Estoy tratando de importar un archivo plan que, según se observa, tiene delimitador "¬". Dejo una muestra del contenido:

```
estu_exam¬estu¬periodo¬consecutivo¬edad
exam¬1¬2010¬001¬16
```

Uso primero readr para importar y obtengo:

```
df<-read_delim("archivo.txt",delim="¬")
head(df)
  `estu_exam\xc2` `estu\xc2` `periodo\xc2` `consecutivo\xc2`  `edad\xc2`
  <chr>           <chr>      <chr>         <chr>              <chr>
1 exam\xc2        1\xc2      2010\xc2      001\xc2            16\xc2
```

En un principio pensé que era problema del encoding. Usé

```
guess_encoding("archivo.txt")


     encoding     confidence
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 UTF-8              1   
2 windows-1251       0.4 
3 windows-1252       0.28
```

Señalando que es UTF-8 con casi total seguridad, que es el que tengo por defecto para R. Descarté esa opción.
Luego intenté con read.delim, read.table y read.csv usando como argumento sep="¬" pero sigo obteniendo resultados similares.

¿Alguno que sepa por qué sucede y como solucionarlo? y si en efecto es un problema de encoding y no lo estoy abordando correctamente.

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Con R 4.0.2 hago `read_delim()` con tu ejemplo y obtengo un error `Error in make.names(x) : invalid multibyte string at '<ac>estu'`, ¿podrías compartir un enlace al archivo?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Guardé el txt en este Drive:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DchkbB9hQC3gaoyReyQ7MEnLSj0zgdtq/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo del que partes, efectivamente parece ser un `utf-8-bom`, es decir de lo que tiene el identificador en los dos primeros bytes, en sí esto no es un problema, el problema es el delimitador, que es un caracter multibyte. Esto en las funciones de R base directamente no está permitido.

```
read.delim("SB11_20101.txt", sep="¬")
Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  valor de 'sep' inválido: debe ser de un byte
```

En el caso de las funciones de `readr` pareciera que hace parte del trabajo bien, aceptar un delimitador multibyte, en este caso es el [`0xC2 0xAC`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ac/index.htm) pero luego  resuelve mal la división de columnas, y parte del delimitador termina dentro de los datos: `0xC2`. No he encontrado ninguna referencia en la red que ayude a resolver este tema, por lo que lo único que se me ocurre, es directamente reeplazar este separador por uno más estándar, por ejemplo el pipe `|` y luego sí leer el archivo:

```
normalize_delim_with_pipe <- function(src, dst, delim) {
  txt <- gsub(pattern = delim, replace = "|", x = readLines(src))
  writeLines(txt, con = dst)
}

normalize_delim_with_pipe("SB11_20101.txt", "SB11_20101.new.txt", "¬")

df <- read.delim("SB11_20101.new.txt", sep="|")
```

#### Actualización:

Lástima que no está en la ayuda, pero en este [`issue`](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/820) de `readr` podemos leer:

> readr assumes only single byte delimiters. You will have to convert
> these multi-byte delimiters to a single byte delimiter such as , or \t
> in a pre-processing step before using readr.

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho . Intenté con la función que propones pero no me funcionó. Sin embargo, me sirvió mucho la aclaración que hiciste del encoding UTF-8-BOM. Al respecto y cómo solucionarlo usé  `df <- read.delim("archivo.txt", sep = "¬", FileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")` siguiendo esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624796/read-a-utf-8-text-file-with-bom